# Unable to find suitable output format for 'libmp3lame' and 'flv'

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, streaming

Currently I am trying to setup a livestream using ffmpeg in Kubuntu. I got really far, but unfortunately I cannot figure out one bit that mentions output format errors. Here's the code I am using for my .sh file:

```
#! /bin/bash

# streaming on Ubuntu via ffmpeg.
# see http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Screencasts for full documentation

# input resolution, currently fullscreen.
# you can set it manually in the format "WIDTHxHEIGHT" instead.
INRES="1920x1200"

# output resolution.
# keep the aspect ratio the same or your stream will not fill the display.
OUTRES="1280x720"

# input audio. You can use "/dev/dsp" for your primary audio input.
#INAUD="pulse"

# target fps
FPS="30"

# video preset quality level.
# more FFMPEG presets avaiable in /usr/share/ffmpeg
QUAL="ultrafast"

# stream key. You can set this manually, or reference it from a hidden file     
like what is done here.
STREAM_KEY=$(cat ~/.twitch_key)

# stream url. Note the formats for twitch.tv and justin.tv
# twitch:"rtmp://live.twitch.tv/app/$STREAM_KEY"
# justin:"rtmp://live.justin.tv/app/$STREAM_KEY"
STREAM_URL="rtmp://live-cdg.twitch.tv/app/$STREAM_KEY"

ffmpeg \
-f alsa -ac 2 -i "$INAUD" \
-f x11grab -s "$INRES" -r "$FPS" -i :50.0 \
-vcodec libx264 -s "$OUTRES" -preset "$QUAL" -crf 22\
-acodec libmp3lame -threads 6 -q:a 0 -b:a 160k \
-f flv -ar 44100 "$STREAM_URL"
```

Now the issue is that whenever I run the .sh file, I get an error at the end saying

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for 'libmp3lame'
libmp3lame: Invalid argument
```

So I decided to troubleshoot by removing the audio line at the bottom and it just turned into

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for 'flv'
flv: Invalid argument
```

Something tells me this is because the stream key is not defined properly, but I have no idea whatsoever how to fix this.

So does anyone have an idea? 
Thanks in advance!

Misterff1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert a space here:

```
-crf 22\
```

so

```
-crf 22 \
```